# Missing required architecture x86_64, i386

Tags: ios

I am trying to build an Application where I have already source code with me and which is not developed by me. I the project seems using a static library `testlib.a` and I can see the in the project the library contains only header and the pre-compiled library `testlib.a`.

And the problem is when I trying to build the source code,

I am getting following error like,

```
testlib.a, missing required architecture x86_64
testlib.a, missing required architecture i386
undefined symbol for architecture x86_64
undefined symbol for architecture i386
```

Does the above means, I cannot use the pre-compiled static library which already  included with the project?(The main problem I am going to face here is I don’t have the source code for the library if I have to rebuild it to create universal library).

How can I resolve this issue?.

Comment: Try to build with "Build Active Architecture Only" with real device. "x86_64, i386" is used for simulators. Maybe someone missed config when build the *.a file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, so is it necessary to connect a ios device to development PC?.

Comment: Yes. Try with real device. Build after chose real device.